# Make div animate up and down with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im trying to get a div move up and down from its current position during a mouse hover event - I have the followng but it only works once and then stops as opposed to continually cycling?

```
tiptitle.stop(true, true).animate({
    'top': '5px'
}, 100).stop(true, true).animate({
    'top': '0px'
}, 100);
```

Comment: Well, yes. Where is the code that you think should make this repeat indefinitely? Hint: it's not there.

Comment: Perhaps a bit more code?

Comment: You may be looking for a shaking effect :) like [THIS](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/Shake)

Answer (score 2):

make an infinite loop

```
function animate(isOpen) {
    tiptitle.stop().animate({'top': isOpen ? '5px' : '0px'}, 100, function() { animate(!isOpen); })
}
```

Comment: Problem 1: how would you break out of this when the mouse is no longer over the tiptitle? Problem 2: how would you make this reusable for more than one element (ie. it's hardcoded to the one object, not very good for reuse if they have multiple items that need this hover effect).

Comment: he never said anything about stopping and obviously you would either pass in the top title as a variable or make it in there. this is just a quick example to point him in the direction of what he asked for